# Dynamically created tabs getting error: Uncaught Error: jQuery UI Tabs: Mismatching fragment identifier. at Function.error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

Dynamically created tabs, but getting this kind of error, I don't know where I went wrong, and `tabindex` is -1 if `i` check in developer console.

```
<div id="tabDiv">
    <ul id="tabs" class="nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"> <a href="#1" onclick="getList();" data-toggle="tab">All</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    function addTabs(result) {
        var unit = _.map(result, 'unit');
        unit = _.uniq(unit);
        var tabs = $("#tabDiv").tabs();
        for (var i = 0; i < unit.length; i++) {
            var ul = tabs.find("ul");
            var current_idx = ul.find("li").length + 2; // Get correct index for id
            $("<li><a href=#" + current_idx + " tabindex=" + ul.find("li").length + " onclick=getList(); data-toggle=tab>" + unit[i] + "</a></li>").appendTo(ul);
            onclick = "getList('wip_production');"
            tabs.tabs("refresh")
        }
        $("</ul>").appendTo(tabs);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You call `getList()` and that does not exist in your code, and where do you use `addTabs(result)` Please include all relevant code if we shall have a chance of helping you

Comment: Version of JqueryUI and Jquery you used please?

Comment: <script>
 function getList(){
  var activeTab = ($('.nav-tabs .active').text());
  console.log(activeTab)
 }
 </script>

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

Comment: activeTab = ($('.nav-tabs .active').text(). this is getting last selected data